# jQuery trigger delegated event

Tags: jquery, events

I've got event:

```
$(document).on("click", ".someClass", function(e){ /*stuff*/ }));
```

Then I'm making `$(".someClass").trigger("click");` but nothing happens.

I think that I would need to trigger event on document somehow... Is there any way to trigger event some way as it would be really clicked so delegated events will be fired too?

Also - I've got multiple elements of `someClass` items and sometimes I need to trigger it only on single of them.

Comment: You can try `$(".someClass")[0].click();` It will trigger DOM element native click event

Comment: Possible with any event name?

Comment: "I need to trigger it only on single of them" So, how do you target this specific one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines should work:

```
var $container = $('.container');

// create a button
var $button = $('<input value="Click me!" class="btn" type="button"/>');

// add button to container
$container.append($button);

// click listener
$container.on('click', '.btn', function() {
    alert('Triggered');
});

// Create an event
var event = jQuery.Event('click');
event.target = $container.find('[type=button]')[0];

// Trigger the event on the container
$container.trigger(event);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4F8dz/)**